# Spring schedule not run on time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I meet a question of spring schedule task using @Schedule annotation. Here is my cron

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0/1 * * ?")
```

It should be run on every hour such as 00:00:00. It also runs fine in my local, but when I deployed it on server side, it is always run in xx:59:59:xxx, a little ahead of settings. I'm not quite sure why cause this problem. My spring version is springboot-1.5.13.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

If your code runs fine on your local machine, at least the code is fine. The remaining question is why the log print time is not what you expected. There may be several reasons.

1. Whether the remote server and the time server are calibrating time.
2. Whether the time obtained in the log is the time of the machine.
3. How did you print the log before or after the task was executed?